# Solving (in)exact differential equation in general form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

given is $y' - p(x)\cdot y - q(x) = 0$. Here I set $g(x,y) = -p(x)y - q(x)$ and $h(x,y)=1$

First, I searched an integrating factor, which has to be dependent only to x. So by $m$ using $\frac{m'}{m} = \frac{h_x - g_y}{u_y\cdot g - u_x\cdot h}$ and because u is only dependant on x, I get $\frac{m'}{m} = \frac{0 - (-p(x))}{-1} = -p(x)$.

So integrating factor is $e^{\int{-p(x)dx}}$

Multiplying with the given differential equation:

$e^{\int -p(x)dx} \cdot(-p(x)y - q(x)) + e^{\int -p(x)dx}y'=0$

Now I'd like to solve this exact(!) differential equation.
Setting $g^*(x,y)= e^{\int -p(x)dx} \cdot(-p(x)y - q(x))$ I want to calculate:

$\int g^*(x,y) dx$ first. But how to do this? How do I integrate $e^{\int ...}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will work, but it's the long way around.  If you treat your DE as "linear", the integrating factor is immediately seen to be the same as what you have, but with much less work.

Now going from your first displayed equation, multiply out the first set of
parens and re-arrange to get

$$e^{\int -p(x)\; dx}(-p(x)y) + e^{\int -p(x)\; dx}y' = e^{\int -p(x)\; dx}q(x).$$

Notice that the left side is the product rule derivative of

$$e^{\int -p(x)\; dx}y,$$

so your equation looks like

$$\left(e^{\int -p(x)\; dx}y\right)' =e^{\int -p(x)\; dx}q(x).$$

Integrate both sides and then divide through by $e^{\int -p(x)\; dx}$ to get

$$y = e^{-\int -p(x)\; dx}  \int e^{\int -p(x)\; dx}q(x) \; dx. $$

Comment: Hey there - unfortunately, I have to solve it as an exact DE =/

Comment: That's what I did.  The whole point of "exact" is that the _exact_ derivative of $e^{\int p}y$ appears.  Apparently the point of this exercise is to show that the "linear" technique is just a special case of the "exact" technique.

Comment: After having written my comment, I wrote down your answer and immediately saw what you mean! Thank you very much :)